# burp or belch: what is suitable to say

Tags: vocabulary

Is 'burp' an informal word?

Oxford dictionary mentions it as an informal word but I have heard people using this normally. Interesting to see that the Cambridge dictionary doesn't mention it as an informal word. That's confusing me.

> I'm asking about the gas expelled through the mouth from the stomach.

Comment: See this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501390/difference-between-to-belch-and-to-burp

Comment: **Eructate** is the most formal word, but it's never really used in normal conversation except by people trying to be humorously over-formal. **Burp** is the normal word and I'm not even aware of a common euphemistic phrase (parallel to "passing gas" for farting). Really, I think the most "formal" thing to do is to pretend that this bodily function doesn't exist at all - one says "excuse me" if a burp is audible, but otherwise it's not a topic for polite conversation!